# Android: How do I create a canvas with scaling pan and zoom functionality?

Tags: java, android, canvas, imageview

I've been following the tutorial at this location to create an Android image view that allows a user to pan an image, and pinch-to-zoom:

http://www.northborder-software.com/pinchzoom_and_pan_5.html

It asks for an image from the user's phone to use, but I modified it to use a specific image I've provided in the drawable folder:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final int MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 101;
private static final int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
private Button getImage;
protected PinchZoomPan pinchZoomPan;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    pinchZoomPan = (PinchZoomPan) findViewById(R.id.ivImage);

    askForRuntimePermission();




    Uri selectedImage = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.nbstutorials.pinchzoompan/drawable/map2");
    pinchZoomPan.loadImageOnCanvas(selectedImage);



}

private void askForRuntimePermission() {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE:
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //permission is granted do nothing in this case
            } else {
                //permission denied
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "this app requires permission to read external storage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }

    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        Uri selectedImage = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.nbstutorials.pinchzoompan/drawable/map2");


        pinchZoomPan.loadImageOnCanvas(selectedImage);


}
}
```

This works great, but when I attempt to draw a line in the **PinchZoomPan.java** method `onDraw`, it doesn't work the way I want it to. This is what happens:

It draws the line on the image. The line remains static; if I draw it in the upper corner of the image when it loads initially, and I pan away from where it was, the line doesn't stay in the corner. I believe that the issue is that the canvas is on top of the image, and the image is panning beneath it while the canvas remains static.

How do I fix this? I want to be able to draw a line in a certain spot on the image itself, and have the panning and zooming affect the line as well. I wonder if there's a way to create/parse a new image with the necessary lines drawn on it, then load *that* image into the viewer?

Also, I'm not attached to this method. If one exists that would work better for my purposes, please let me know.

Thank you.